# Setting for default routing of / to /home

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Inside of `Views/Home` directory, I have `index.cshtml` file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Movies API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Movies API</h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a Movies Controller class as follows:

```
namespace MoviesAPI.Controllers
{
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     public class MoviesController : Controller
     {
          private MoviesDbContext _context;
          public MoviesController(MoviesDbContext context)
          {
               _context = context;
          }
          public IActionResult GetMovies()
          {
               return Ok(_context.Movies);
          }
     }
}
```

And a `Startup.cs` file with the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using MoviesAPI.Services;

// Remember, this code requires mssql to be running. docker ps -a

namespace MoviesAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString =
               "Server=localhost;Database=MoviesDB;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd!";
               services.AddDbContext<MoviesDbContext>(o =>
                   o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


            //services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);          
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        //public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
               IHostingEnvironment env,
               //IHostEnvironment env,
               MoviesDbContext moviesDbContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            //app.UseAuthorization();
            moviesDbContext.CreateSeedData();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

I start the project by:

```
dotnet run
```

I get a warning that appears harmless on the command line:

```
Startup.cs(38,16): warning CS0618: 'IHostingEnvironment' is obsolete: 'This type is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment.' [/Users/ivanfigueredo/Documents/Projects/MoviesAPI/MoviesAPI.csproj]
```

but eventually this shows:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /Users/ivan/Documents/Projects/MoviesAPI
```

- When I browse to http://localhost:5000/api/movies the api getting data from SqlServer displays
  fine.
- When I browse to `http://localhost:5000/home` everything
  displays as it should from the `index` file.
- However, if I browse to http://localhost:5000 nothing
  displays and I get an `HTTP ERROR 404`

**Is there some setting that routes `/` to `/home`? What's the accepted way to do this?**

I looked around, and saw things like this, but I can't make it work:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("/", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: In the last route map Instead of / use any understandable name for route like default or root etc.

Comment: @Ivan does below answer works?

Answer (score 0):

Below line is

```
 app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

converted internally to

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
            });
```

You can check the implementation here 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs . So leave it like that.

Coming back to your question

```
http://localhost:5000 //returns 404
```

To set home controller as your default controller,you need to follow attribute routing ,so decorate the HomeController like this

```
[Route("~/”)
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

By following this you are defining in your application that let Home controller be the default routing controller if the url is blank without any segments after port number and inside that index method is the default action method as you told you are able to browse /home . Hope this answers your question in detail.